# Select data within a certain range?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve all info from the table 'Players' where the age is greater than (or equal to) 18 but less than (or equal to) 25.

So far I have:

```
SELECT *
FROM Players
WHERE _______ BETWEEN _____;
```

What do I put in the spaces to achieve this?
(I am required to use the above format)

Comment: This looks like assignment question.

Comment: This is no way to learn SQL.  You should try solving this yourself, and only come here for help if you really need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM Players
WHERE age BETWEEN 18 and 35
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below - using `age>=18 and age<=35` as condition in where clause

```
SELECT *
FROM Players
WHERE age>=18 and age<=35
```